# Python code to fetch SQL queries along with its column names and convert it to following json format

Tags: python, json, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I have tried fetching SQL query results and converting it into JSON format. I have partially succeeded. However I am looking for the following format:

```
[
{
   "JId": 1,
    "Jinfo": "Failed",
   "Jno": "Job1"
},
{
    "JId":2,
    "Jinfo":"Failed",
    "Jno":"Job2"
},
{
    "JId":3,
    "Jinfo":"Failed",
    "Jno":"Job3"
}
]
```

There exists a table named 'jobfail' with following data:

```
JId Jinfo  Jno
1,  "Failed", "Job1"
2,  "Failed", "Job2"
3,  "Failed", "Job3"
```

I was able to retrieve the column name and values separately. I was able to convert the values into JSON also. But I did not get it in "column_name: value" format.

```
import pyodbc
import json

cncn=pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=Server_name;Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
if(cncn):
    print("Connected")
    query1="SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'jobfail'"
    query2="SELECT * FROM dbo.jobfail"
    data=[]
    column_list=[]
    cursor = cncn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query1)
    for cname in cursor.fetchall():
        column_list.append(list(cname))
    print(column_list)
    cursor.execute(query2)
    rs=cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rs:
        data.append(list(row))
    print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

I expect the output to be in the above mentioned format. I could not merge the column name and respective values to form JSON. Below is the partial The output I got.

```
[['jid'], ['Jinfo'], ['Jno']]             


[
[
    1,
    "Failed",
    "Job1"
],
[
    2,
    "Failed",
    "Job2"
],
[
    3,
    "Failed",
    "Job3"
]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server will return query results to you [as JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) if you want.  EG

```
use tempdb
drop table if exists #t
go
create table #t(JId int, Jinfo varchar(30), Jno varchar(30))


insert into #t
values
(1,  'Failed', 'Job1'),
(2,  'Failed', 'Job2'),
(3,  'Failed', 'Job3')

go
select *
from #t t
for json path
```

outputs

```
[
    {
        "JId": 1,
        "Jinfo": "Failed",
        "Jno": "Job1"
    },
    {
        "JId": 2,
        "Jinfo": "Failed",
        "Jno": "Job2"
    },
    {
        "JId": 3,
        "Jinfo": "Failed",
        "Jno": "Job3"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. May I know is it possible to do the same using python code?